# Javascript: What does this `Array(i+1)` do?

Tags: javascript

Hi I found a solution for a problem on codewars and I'm not sure what a piece of the syntax does. The function takes a string of characters, and based on the length, returns it in a certain fashion.

input = "abcd"; output = "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
input = "gFkLM"; output = "G-Ff-Kkk-Llll-Mmmmm"

This guy posted this solution

```
function accum(str) {
  var letters = str.split('');
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    result.push(letters[i].toUpperCase() + Array(i + 1).join(letters[i].toLowerCase()));
  }
  return result.join('-');
}
```

Kinda confused about the solution overall, but one thing is particularly nagging me. See that `Array(i + 1)` ? What does that do? Sorry, not a very easy thing to google.

Comment: Array(n) creates an Array of  length `n`

Comment: Cool trick. Ty!

Comment: Sometimes these are used for interview questions, where the interviewer wants to see how the interviewee thinks & what they do when they get stuck. They want to know if a person gets angry at a problem or if they are OK with being stuck & open to asking for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that this allocates an array of length `i + 1`.  But more importantly, what is the code doing?  You have to know what the `join()` function does... It concatenates elements in an array delimitated by the function argument.  For example:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'].join(' ') === 'one two three'
```

In this case, the array is filled with `undefined` elements, so you get something like this:

```
[undefined].join('a') === ''
[undefined, undefined].join('b') === 'b'
[undefined, undefined, undefined].join('c') === 'cc'
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined].join('d') === 'ddd'
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful - I understand all of the code now. What a creative solution.

Comment: No problem! After reading @RafiqueAhmed's answer, I realized that the array is initialized with `undefined` elements instead of `null` elements and have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

So in the beginning for statement,    i    starts out at 0. Now if you go inside the for statement where it says i+1, i would be 1. And then when the for loop updates and i equals 1, i+1 inside the for loop would equal 2. This process would continue for the length of the string. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked

```
let x= Array(3);
console.log(x);
```

The output is [undefined, undefined, undefined]

So it actually creates array of size 3 with all the elements as undefined.
When we call join wit a character as param it creates a string with the same character repeating 2 times i.e (3-1).

```
console.log(x.join('a')); //  logs aa
```

Answer (score 0):

Commented code walk-though ....

```
function accum(str) {
    /* converts string to character array.*/
    var letters = str.split('');
    /* variable to store result */
    var result = [];
    /* for each character concat (1.) + (2.) and push into results.
       1. letters[i].toUpperCase() :
            UPPER-CASE of the character.
       2. Array(i + 1).join(letters[i].toLowerCase()) :
            create an array with EMPTY SLOTS of length that is, +1 than the current index. 
            And join them to string with the current charater's LOWER-CASE as the separator.

            Ex:
            Index   |   ArrayLength, Array      |   Separator   |   Joined String
            0           1, [null]                   'a'             ''
            1           2, [null,null]              'b'             'b'
            2           3, [null,null,null]         'c'             'cc'
            3           4, [null,null,null,null]    'd'             'ddd'

            NOTE: 
            Join on an array with EMPTY SLOTS, inserts the seperator inbetween the slot values.
            Meaning, if N is the length of array. Then there will be N-1 seperators inserted into the joined string

    */
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        result.push(letters[i].toUpperCase() + Array(i + 1).join(letters[i].toLowerCase()));
    }

    /* finally join all sperated by '-' and return ...*/
    return result.join('-');
}
```